# Error while installing Bcache on centOS

Tags: centos, cache, bcache

I am trying to setup Bcache on my existing system(Its risky,but we are not worried about losing any data ) .
So my make and make install works proper but when I run the command make-bcache i receive the below error .The same error I received when I try to setup dm-cache .Can any one please suggest any solutions ,are we doing any mistake here

```
[root@x130-65-157-206 bcache-tools]# make-bcache -B /dev/sda2
Can't open dev /dev/sda2: Device or resource busy 

[root@x130-65-157-206 bcache-tools]# make-bcache -B /dev/sda
Can't open dev /dev/sda: Device or resource busy
```

Below is config of my disk

```
[root@x130-65-157-206 bcache-tools]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 498.8 GB, 498753077248 bytes, 974127104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00036dc2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048   974127103   486550528   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 8455 MB, 8455716864 bytes, 16515072 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 436.0 GB, 436014678016 bytes, 851591168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 31.4 GB, 31376707072 bytes, 61282631 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

My SSD is present at /dev/sdb .

Answer (score 1):

You have LVM set up on `/dev/sda2`, so you need to run `make-bcache` on the logical volumes (LVs) instead of the raw partition. If you want to use both the `centos-root` and `centos-home` LVs as backing devices and the entire SSD as a cache device, you can set this up with

```
make-bcache --bdev /dev/mapper/centos-root /dev/mapper/centos-home --cache /dev/sdb
```

See `make-bcache --help` for more options.

You will need to update your initramfs and fstab to boot succesfully.

I highly recommend reading the [kernel documentation for bcache](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/bcache.txt).